# What distribution results from drawing random numbers whose upper bound is normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have a normal distribution $N$ with $μ=U/2$ and $σ=U/12$ (an approximation of the Irwin-Hall distribution) which has been bounded and normalized to $[0,U]$.

I will now repeatedly generate random numbers $r$ from a uniform distribution with the range $[0,n]$, where $n$ is drawn from $N$.

Is there a name for the distribution formed by the many $r$?

The density of the new distribution seems to be approximated by the complementary cumulative distribution function of the normal normalized by a factor $\frac{10}{\sum\textrm{ccdf}}$.

Comment: In fact that is exactly what the probability distribution function is.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. The CDF integrates to more than 1, so it isn't an appropriate PDF.

Comment: If you're restricting the normal random variable, your have to normalize it's PDF to integrate to 1. It's no longer normal, technically. It's kind of like a truncated normal.

Comment: Yes, the truncated normal has been normalized.

Comment: Assuming that in the first step one uses the normal distribution with variance $1$, the construction you describe yields $N$ with PDF $$f(x)=\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\int_x^1\frac{\varphi(x-u/2)}{1-2\Phi(u/2)}du,$$ where $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ denote the standard normal PDF and CDF, and $R$ with PDF $$g(y)=\mathbf 1_{0<y<1}\int_y^1f(x)\frac{dx}x,$$ with no obvious simplification.